# How do I create editable TextFields and pre-populate them with data from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I am attempting to combine two things:

1. I want to pre-populate a `TextField` with data pulled from an API
2. I want to give the user the ability to edit the `TextField`

I can do each of these things independently (see below), but I am trying to get TextField components that let me do both at the same time.

Any ideas on how to mash these together?

**Code:**

```
// imports ...

function getDataFromApi() {
  return fetch("https://api.example.com/...", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      return responseData;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
}

function myFunction(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => { getDataFromApi(props.id).then((response) => setData(response)); }, []);

  const [textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue] = useState("I am pre-populated");

  const handleTextFieldChange = useCallback(
    (value) => setTextFieldValue(value),
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        <TextField // <----- THIS TEXTFIELD LETS ME PRE-POPULATE THE FIELD'S VALUE, BUT NOT EDIT IT
          id="favoriteAnimal"
          placeholder="example: zebra"
          value={data.details?.favoriteAnimal}
          onChange={handleTextFieldChange}
        />
        <TextField // <----- THIS TEXTFIELD LETS ME EDIT THE FIELD'S VALUE, BUT NOT PRE-POPULATE IT
          id="favoriteAnimal"
          placeholder="example: zebra"
          value={textFieldValue}
          onChange={handleTextFieldChange}
        />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define text field value state first, then in your response handling, set the text field value.

```
const [favoriteAnimal, setFavoriteAnimal] = useState('');

useEffect(() => { 
  getDataFromApi(props.id).then((response) => {
    setFavoriteAnimal(response.details?.favoriteAnimal));
  }); 
}, []);

const handleFavoriteAnimalChange = useCallback(...);

return (
  <TextField
    id="favoriteAnimal"
    placeholder="example: zebra"
    value={favoriteAnimal}
    onChange={handleFavoriteAnimalChange}
  />
)
```

Note, though, while the data is fetching, the text field value will be `''` (or whatever you initialized in `useState`), so ideally you would implement some loading-state UI.

EDIT:
If you need multiple editable data points, you can keep separate states+handlers or a unified state+handler.

Separate states, separate handlers

```
const [favoriteAnimal, setFavoriteAnimal] = useState('');
const [favoritePlant, setFavoritePlant] = useState('');

useEffect(() => { 
  // ... load the data and set it
}, []);

const handleChangeFavoriteAnimal = (e) => setFavoriteAnimal(e.target.value);
const handleChangeFavoritePlant = (e) => setFavoritePlant(e.target.value);

return (
  <>
    <TextField
      value={favoriteAnimal}
      onChange={handleChangeFavoriteAnimal}
    />
    <TextField
      value={favoritePlant}
      onChange={handleChangeFavoritePlant}
    />
  </>
);
```

Unified state, unified handler

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState({
  animal: '',
  plant: ''
});

useEffect(() => { 
  // ... load the data and set it
}, []);

const handleChangeFavorite = (type) => (e) => {
  setFavorites(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   [type]: e.target.value
  });
}

return (
  <>
    <TextField
      value={favorites.animal}
      onChange={handleChangeFavorite('animal')}
    />
    <TextField
      value={favorites.plant}
      onChange={handleChangeFavorite('plant')}
    />
  </>
);
```

Unified state, separate handlers

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState({
  animal: '',
  plant: ''
});

useEffect(() => { 
  // ... load the data and set it
}, []);

const handleChangeFavoriteAnimal = (e) => {
  setFavorites(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   animal: e.target.value
  });
}
const handleChangeFavoritePlant = (e) => {
  setFavorites(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   plant: e.target.value
  });
}

return (
  <>
    <TextField
      value={favorites.animal}
      onChange={handleChangeFavoriteAnimal}
    />
    <TextField
      value={favorites.plant}
      onChange={handleChangeFavoritePlant}
    />
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @bsapaka. What would I need to tweak if I had 2 or 3 additional textfields that I also wanted to populate from the API? It looks like the code you shared would only allow me to edit one of them unless I created a bunch of `textFieldValue` functions

Comment: You can create multiple states, where each state is named after its piece of data. (for example, I renamed `textFieldValue` to `favoriteAnimal`). Alternatively, you can keep a state object that holds all your values.

Comment: Very nice, complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to wait for the data to return from the API and render the component with data passed in as props once the API has given you

For example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-glitter-3njd9?file=/src/App.js

There's an `if` statement in the main `App` component that if the API has returned with data, will render `MyComponent`, otherwise it will display "API Content not loaded."

You can do this within the same component if desired, but because fetch returns a promise that will not resolve instantly, you wouldn't be able to pre-populate the field value with the API response. You'd instead have to have a placeholder that is there while the API content is fetching and then once it has returned update the field value, which I would not recommend as the field's value might update while a user is typing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Alex D. I took a look at the codessandbox.io you created, but that text field does not appear to let me edit the content. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: I left out some things, it'll need the change handler. I can put that in real fast.

Comment: I updated it with your change handler. https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-glitter-3njd9?file=/src/App.js